# permutation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\sigma=(132)(45)$ be a permutation, we construct the matrix $A$ such that its $i'$th collumn is the $\sigma(i)'$th colllumn of $I_5$.

so the matrix which I got is ${A}=\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{0}&{1}&{0}&0&0&0\\
{0}&{0}&{1}&0&0&0\\
{1}&{0}&{0}&0&0&0\\
{0}&{0}&{0}&0&0&1\\
{0}&{0}&{0}&0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right]$

now I need to say which of the followng is correct?

1. $A^3=I$
2. $A^5=I$
3. $A^6=I$
4. $A^2=I$

without doing product how to say the answer? what is the underlying theory here?

thanks

Comment: The product of two permutation matrices is again a permutation matrix.

Comment: :(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(

Comment: Isn't composing the same permutation equivalent to raising the matrix $A$ to some power? E.g. $\sigma \circ \sigma$ should give the permutation matrix equal to $A^2$. At least it seems so. The you are looking for $n$ for which $\sigma^n = id$. That is 6.

Comment: Note that the lower right block to an even power is $I$, while an odd power is $[0,1;1,0]$.

Comment: The fourth row is null, so this is not a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying theory is that the function you describe taking $\sigma$ to the matrix $A_\sigma$ is an isomorphism when applied to all $\sigma \in S_5$. You should convince yourself that $\sigma(i)=j \iff A_\sigma(e_i)=e_j$, where $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector.

Answer (score 1):

your permutation has two cycles one of length $3$ and the other of length $2.$ the permutation is of the order $6$ which is the least common multiple of the orders. i expect $A^6 = I.$